# Is there a JavScript event when DOM content stops updating?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, timer

I am building a website whose main component is a slideshow that is in the background of the whole site. Its image and description are on a timer so they change every couple of seconds.

The problem is that when the user leaves the site for a long enough time, the timer is still running, but the content is not present anymore, so when they navigate back to the page, it tries to catch up to the timer and it goes through the slideshow very quickly until it gets to the right state.

My current (very simple) solution for this is that I am cheching if the document is in focus before going to the next slide:

```
    //- show next slide
    function nextSlide() {
        if (!document.hasFocus()) return
    ...
```

The problem with this solution is that if there are multiple windows on the screen and the page is not in focus, then the slideshow won't play, which isn't the intended bahaviour.

My question is: is there any JavaScript event that I can rely on to be called when the document is unloaded but the scripts are still running (if that even is what is happening here), so I can stop the timer and start it again when the user navigates to the site?

**Edit**: when I said "leaving the site", I meant leaving the tab or switching to another window so the site loses focus.

Link to the site: https://dev.jazzpuntbigband.com

Comment: Scripts stop automatically when the page is unloaded. There's an `unload` event that fires when it's about to be unloaded.

Comment: @Barmar I said I wasn't sure that an unload is what's happening. If, as you said, the scripts stop on `unload`, then `unload` isn't the problem. I am quite sure that the script is still running and the page content is not present or else this wouldn't be happening. That's why I need someone more familiar with the states and events of a webpage than I am.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is. You say they "leave the site for a long enough time". As soon as you leave a site, the page is unloaded and scripts stop. Are you talking about switching to another window or tab? That doesn't leave the site, it just takes focus away from it. Scripts keep running, but with lower priority.

Comment: @Barmar I meant "leaving the site" as in it's still running in the background, it lost its focus. Am I right in assuming that the script is still running in the background but the changes to the document are somehow queued so that when the tab is opened again they happen right after one another?

Comment: I guess it's more of a terminology issue, but I don't consider you to have "left" the site if it's still in a browser tab or window. You leave it when you close the tab or link to another site. If you open a new window for some other site, the old site is still open in the first window; scripts keep running, but maybe at lower priority.

Comment: @Barmar we've already established it's a terminology issue. Now that it's clear what the problem is, can you help or not?
If it's still not clear, the issue is reproducible if you visit the website provided in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed my own issue. Turns out all I had to do was follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) guide from MDN Web Docs.